# Display Unicode character with MIPS

Tags: assembly, unicode, mips, mars-simulator

How do I print a unicode character (for instance - U+263A ☺) with MIPS?

If possible I would like to use the MARS MIPS simulator to perform this task but it's not required.

Edit: According to Erik Eidt this is not possible in MARS, so answers for other runtime environments are fine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think MARS supports unicode.  I tried print char, and then print string with utf-8, but they just showed boxes each byte it didn't recognize...

Comment: any Linux terminals support Unicode so you don't need any special support. It all depends on the terminal if you're writing a CLI. If you use GUI then there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: @phuclv: are you sure? UTF-8 in Linux is relatively recent, and it requires various libraries. GUI are worst. You do not know if they are Unicode compatible (the version your are using) and it you have all libraries updated (and with modern Unicode version).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi UTF-8 support has been introduced since glibc 2.2 which was released in 2000. Since then it has been the default locale in Linux. I'm sure if the OP is using Linux it's definitely not an 20-year-old distro. But it's unclear which other "runtime environment" the OP wants

Comment: @phuclv The environment is [MARS](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/). Please stay on topic.

Comment: @daxim please read the last sentence: *According to Eric Eidt this is not possible in MARS so any runtime environment is fine*

Comment: @phuclv I am mostly curious about what the format would look like, so feel free to pick any runtime environment. Just be sure to specify what you environment you pick.

Comment: @DivideByZero Unicode is just a set of mapping between integers and characters. It doesn't have any format. There are multiple ways to encode it like UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 and to display it you just ensure that the encoding is the same as what the printing procedure expects (normally UTF-8 in modern Unix systems). There's nothing special about that unless you want to transform the string

Comment: It's not that MARS doesn't support unicode, say, in file names and such.  It is that the MARS emulator does not appear to support unicode/UTF-8 in the emulated MIPS syscalls for print char (11) and print string (4), which are supposed to be echoed in the emulator's "Run IO" console terminal.

Answer (score 1):

MARS allows for various plugins.  You might be able to write a plug-in that captures output bytes, and either sends to a file or displays on another program's console window (where unicode is supported).